# My phone (htc g8 wildfire os2.1) not support LinkedIn

Tags: android, linkedin-api

```
11-17 15:04:15.477: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): ***Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception***
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): ***com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException:*** ***oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed:*** htts:///api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:146)
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at com.ceosoft.alumlife.util.LinkedInAuthenticateHelper.getRequestToken(LinkedInAuthenticateHelper.java:66)
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at com.ceosoft.alumlife.util.LinkedInAuthenticateHelper.authenticateApp(LinkedInAuthenticateHelper.java:53)
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at 
.....
....
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): ***Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: htts:///api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken***
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:138)
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): ... 25 more
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): ***Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/.//api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken***
11-17 15:04:15.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3411): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.
....
....
```

***My code as follows:***

```
private LinkedInRequestToken getRequestToken() {

   Log.d(TAG, "API_KEY = " + OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY);
   Log.d(TAG, "SECRET_KEY = " + OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET );

   mOauthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
   Log.d(TAG, "mOauthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()");
   requestToken = mOauthService.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL); //this line occur error
   Log.d(TAG, "LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = mOauthService");
   return requestToken;

}
```

---

I don't have power put more than one hyperlink  at here.
So I'm sorry!

Note:   "htts" it means https
        "///" is "//"

Comment: htts:///api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken.
shouldn't it be http:// or https://

Comment: I'm very sorry for you.  I ask question in this web site as a guest.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is :

My phone's time setting have problem.  Not my application. Need the correct time setting if you want to use LinkedIn.

Comment: I had changed my device time still i am facing same error....FileNotFoundException.....

Comment: Hello Samuel, can you share your code... so, i can compare it and found some required changes.... Thanks in Advance.... :)

Answer (score 0):

@samuel.  not sure if I understand what you mean Note: "htts" it mean https but I just looked at the linkedin API and it says https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken.

Answer (score 0):

I had my time 8 mins ahead and solved it putting it back to the real time

Ashok's answer
[Android LinkedIn Integration Error on Device And Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562584/android-linkedin-integration-error-on-device-and-emulator)

*"Time,Date and Timezone should be correct if anything is wrong or even 1 min difference will give this exception".*