# Android LinkedIn Integration Error on Device And Emulator

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrated linkedIn using this question answer [Posting LinkedIn message from Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804257/posting-linkedin-message-from-android-application)
 but this given example LITest in not working on Device is Shows me some Error like below

```
  12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.osadkowski.LITest/pl.osadkowski.LITest.LITestActivity}: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868): Caused by: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:180)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at pl.osadkowski.LITest.LITestActivity.onCreate(LITestActivity.java:49)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     ... 11 more
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868): Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:172)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     ... 14 more
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:253)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
12-19 19:36:30.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11868):     ... 16 more
```

When i run it on Emulator it will ask me for Authorization of app, i had grant the App.
After the i will not be redirected to the app. Please see below image.

[image]

Comment: linkedin-j stops working ... https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken ... 404

Comment: Sorry, but linkedin-j stops working means.... :(

Comment: now it's working ... did you changed API keys ?

Comment: first hand look telling that service is down and your app is not able to connect to it

Comment: Yes, i had changed api keys, set call back url. and also did you know why not working on Device (android Froyo 2.2) ?

Comment: I am able to login in the linked in, problem is that..after login..it is not redirecting to my android app activity...and showing on browser successfully authorized appname, please return to your application and enter the following code to grant access:

Comment: the code is:- oauthflow-linkedin:/itestcalback?auth_token=tokenno&oauth_verfier=verfierno. and in the next line..by granting access you agree to the LinkedIn User agreement and privacy policy.

Comment: hi every one..I completed..LinkedIn integration..very..well..

Comment: m facing the same issue, may i kw how did u solve it?@srinivasaraoramisetty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First Try to clear cookies before you init LinkedIn related object... Use Below Code

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Please update me if it works or not....

Comment: Hello RadheMohan, Please provide me some error you facing... Also Check for time is right in device.

Comment: Hi all, I would like to add here, linked-j api is unable to get authFinish in android 4.0 and above..
any updated api

Answer (score 3):

Solved for me..on Device and Emulator.

Time,Date and Timezone should be correct if anything is wrong or even 1 min difference will give this exception.